# How to have special character in JSON

Tags: java, json

Here I have shown the sample JSON object of my project

```
{
    "objectType": "main",
    "description": "",
    "Column": "[{"displayName": "Account Name", "DataType" : "string"}, {"displayName" : "Billing City", "DataType" : "string" }, { "displayName" : "Billing State/Province" , "DataType" : "string" }, {"displayName" : "Billing Street", "DataType" : "textarea"}]"
}
```

It has some special characters like"/" (Billing State/Province) in the display name. Now it was not allowed to convert it to JSONArray and put in the RootJsonObject due to the special character in it. I had used the following code

```
RootJsonObject = new JSONObject();
RootJsonObject.put("content",new JSONArray(JsonObject.getString("Column")));
```

But I need that special character. Is there is any other way to have that "/" in my JSONObject or can I use any other JSON util.

Comment: A problem may be that the column value string is not valid JSON, neither the property names nor the values are quoted.

Comment: / is not a special character, and there is no problem putting any character in JSON, since it's encoded in UTF8 or UTF16. If you have a problem with some code, then post the code. We need a complete minimal example.

Comment: If you want the backslash '\' use '\\'.

Comment: @Henry is is valid JSON. The value of the Column property is a giant string, that does not contain JSON, though, although it vaguely looks like it.

Comment: @JBNizet the whole string is valid, but OP tries to parse the column value again as an array.

Comment: @karthik please refer the below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server

Comment: @Karthik ,This link explains how to escape different special charaters in JSON/Javascript text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FValues%2C_variables%2C_and_literals#String_literals

Comment: Is the `Column` property supposed to be valid JSON or just a big string containing invalid JSON?

Comment: Column is just a big string containing the names and values and it is valid JSON.

Comment: In your example, `Column` is *NOT* valid JSON. As suggested in other comments, it is missing quotation marks and uses `=` instead of `:`. For example, `displayName=Account Name` should be `"displayName": "Account Name"`

Comment: without adding "/" in Billing State/Province it was allowed to put the column in the RootJsonObject.

Comment: And when you say `allowed` do you mean the array was populated correctly with each element and properties correctly deserialised? Or was it just one big string?

Comment: Try `org.json.simple JSONParser and JSONObject`. Was able to get the proper JSON. Of course, `Billing State/Province` is parsed like `Blilling State\/Province`

Comment: @timothyclifford, Actually it was a big string, after passing through some method it will change like the above as I was changed in the sample JSON Object

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've updated your question to include valid JSON for the `Content` property.

When deserialising this string to JSON, you will need to escape any special characters.

[Apache StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-) contains an `escapeJson` method which can do this for you:

```
RootJsonObject = new JSONObject();
String jsonArrayString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(JsonObject.getString("Column"));
RootJsonObject.put("content", new JSONArray(jsonArrayString));
```

I am not 100% clear where `JsonObject` comes from or is populated but if the above does not work, you may need to escape the content earlier in the process somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: You're welcome, please let me know if you are successful or not